# How to Disable HTTP compression or SSL Compression on Apache 2.4.2

Tags: apache, http, ssl, http-compression

I am using the Apache 2.4.2 version so how to disable the HTTP compression or the SSL Compression without upgrading the Apache Version.

Comment: which OS you are using?

Comment: Linux debian as OS

Answer (score 2):

For Debian/Ubuntu

```
sudo a2dismod deflate
```

For Red Hat or CentOS::

Comment out those line

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
and restart apache

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

Tried as suggested by you. Line was like this:

#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so

Updated it as:

LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so

but it didn't work. SSLCompressio is still enable. Did I miss anything?

Comment: You have to keep that commented(starting with #), for debian, did you tried that command  'sudo a2dismod deflate'

Comment: If it don't work then find this file /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf and set SSLCompression off